# How to copy directory using maven copy resoures plugin

Tags: maven, resources, maven-plugin

I have referred the maven documentation here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html to understand about including whatever the files we need. But it has mentioned only about including files. So how can I copy all the directories and files inside a specific directory using maven resources plug-in?

Comment: Which directory would you like to copy? My assumption `src/main/resources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without specifying any includes and excludes so that it picks all directories and files inside the resources directory.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can this resource plugin be used for copying dependencies to the lib directory which resides inside the target's WEB-INF directory?

Comment: I think the mvn package automatically copies all dependencies to WEB-INF/lib. Is there a reason why would you want to do it manually?

Comment: I did it using maven dependency plug-in as resources plug-in is not allow to copy dependencies. Yes I am integrating CAS server with a web app as a separate module. So I need to copy and replace only the modified files to the target directory.

Comment: ok, am glad if you were able to solve your problems using dependency plugin. This particular question was about making resource plugin copy an entire directory and thanks for accepting my answer.